# Flatten N Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have 2 arrays, of the same type and size (L), and I would like to flatten them into either one of the arrays, or into a new array, if the second array's value is 0. Eg:

```
Arr1 = { 0, 1, 2, 5, 0, 7, 6, 8 }
Arr2 = { 0, 0, 3, 1, 9, 2, 0, 1 }
Flat = { 0, 1, 3, 1, 9, 2, 6, 1 }
```

I realise I could do this iteratively (see below) with a comparison, but I feel that there should be a nicer way to express and conduct this operation (hopefully with maximum efficiency).

```
for (var i = 0; i < Arr1.Length; i++)
{
    Arr1[i] = Arr2[i] != 0 ? Arr2[i] : Arr1[i];
}
```

Furthermore, could this be extended to flatten N arrays in an ordered list?

Multi-Array example:

```
Arr1 = { 0, 1, 2, 5, 0, 7, 6, 8 }
Arr2 = { 0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 2, 0, 1 }
Arr3 = { 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }

Flat = { 0, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 6, 1 }
```

...and I suppose this could look something like this in code:

```
// Assume collection is ordered via some predicate
// var myArrays = existingArrays.OrderByDescending(myPredicate).ToList();

// Some function to flatten position 'index'
int FlattenOrderedValues(IEnumerable<int[]> arrays, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Lenth)
    {
        if (arrays[i][index] > 0) return (arrays[i][index];
    }

    return 0;
}

for (var i = 0; i < arrays[0].Length; i++)
{
    arrays[0][i] = FlattenOrderedValues(arrays, i);
}
```

Comment: can you add sample for 3 arrays? what algorithm will be used to calculate value

Comment: I have added a sample for multiple arrays which flattens everything into the first. Note that I haven't tested these samples.
Imagine that the arrays represent a layer with some z-index which they are ordered by.

Comment: your current algorithm is little different - it returns first non-zero value. I.e. Flat will be `{0, 1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 6, 8}`. You should enumerate arrays in reverse order

Comment: I probably shouldn't have written the result to the first array in the ordered example, and instead to a new array. I was hoping the 'OrderByDescending' would illustrate the reversal. By ordering the list in reverse, I am treating the first array as if it was the last.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With LINQ you can [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) both arrays and select result depending on values of two corresponding items from both arrays:

```
var Flat = Arr1.Zip(Arr2, (a1, a2) => a2 == 0 ? a1 : a2).ToArray()
```

---

You can apply same approach several times if you have N arrays. But that will not be very efficient. So simple `for` loop with access by index will do the job. Or you can use LINQ again to access all arrays by index:

```
var Flat =  Enumerable.Range(0, Arr1.Length)
                      .Select(i => Arr2[i] == 0 ? Arr1[i] : Arr2[i]) // use N arrays here
                      .ToArray()
```

UPDATE (for your sample). You can simply select 'columns' for each index and pick last value which is greater than zero

```
var Flat = Enumerable.Range(0, arrays[0].Length)
                     .Select(i => arrays.Select(a => a[i]).LastOrDefault(x => x > 0))
                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading `Sergey`'s answer, I came up with this:

```
int[] Arr1 = { 0, 1, 2, 5, 0, 7, 6, 8 };
int[] Arr2 = { 0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 2, 0, 1 };
int[] Arr3 = { 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 };

int[][] arrays = { Arr1, Arr2, Arr3 };

int[] result = arrays.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Zip(b, (i, j) => j == 0 ? i : j).ToArray());
```

Comment: Cool, maybe not best performance (premature optimization is evil) but very readable

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yeah, I hate that repetitive `ToArray`, but to fix it, the code will grow longer.

Answer (score 0):

Reading these answers I though to give something from myself. Even though these answers are working okay ... they are too long for what they have to do.

My solution would be to just packed all of them into one array and then simply use `SelectMany` method that will automatically stitch these arrays into one.

```
int [] combinedarrays = { array1, array2, array3 };
int [] result = combinedarrays. SelectMany (i => i).Distinct ().ToArray ();
```